# Appending column in dataframe based on rank of values in preceding columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
      Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC    
20 2008-01-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000            
40 2008-02-29  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000   
60 2008-03-31   27.834286  3.764286  25.350000
```

Imagine that these are % returns above. How can I rank the values in the 3 columns so that the dataframe now looks like:

```
      Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC      Rank_Max  Rank_Min
20 2008-01-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000     AAPL      NFLX        
40 2008-02-29  27.847143  33.724286  24.670000    NFLX      INTC
60 2008-03-31   27.834286  3.764286  25.350000    etc
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your data seems to change, e.g. `3.724286` becomes `33.724286`. I assume this is just a typo?

Comment: yes, just typo, example data. Imagine I had more data next to the 3 columns, say 4 more stocks. How could I do the same ranking for that second set of 4 stocks only?

Answer (score 2):

First, find the ranks (this function incidentally filters out any non-numeric columns):

```
ranks = df.rank(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
```

Next, find the indexes of the smallest and the largest ranks:

```
df['Rank_Max'] = ranks.idxmax(axis=1)
df['Rank_Min'] = ranks.idxmin(axis=1)
df
#          Date       AAPL       NFLX   INTC Rank_Max Rank_Min
#20  2008-01-31  27.834286   3.764286  25.35     AAPL     NFLX
#40  2008-02-29  27.847143  33.724286  24.67     NFLX     INTC
#60  2008-03-31  27.834286   3.764286  25.35     AAPL     NFLX
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `idxmax` and `idxmin`:

```
df['Rank_Max'] = df[['AAPL', 'NFLX', 'INTC']].idxmax(axis=1)
df['Rank_Min'] = df[['AAPL', 'NFLX', 'INTC']].idxmin(axis=1)

print(df)

          Date       AAPL      NFLX   INTC Rank_Max Rank_Min
20  2008-01-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.35     AAPL     NFLX
40  2008-02-29  27.847143  3.724286  24.67     AAPL     NFLX
60  2008-03-31  27.834286  3.764286  25.35     AAPL     NFLX
```

Comment: ok thx and how do I apply the .idxmax to certain columns only? Something like:  df['Rank_Max']= df[[5:8]].idxmax() ?

Comment: @EksanaStasis, I've already limited to certain columns by filtering, i.e. `df[['AAPL', 'NFLX', 'INTC']]`. If you want to identify columns by integer location, use `df.iloc[:, 5:8]`.